# T-SQL if isnull() construct

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a piece of t-sql code from stored procedure that executes a search based on given parameters. I can't seem to understand the logic behind the following statement:

```
if isnull(@LoginName, '') = '' 
    select @LoginName = null
```

Here is my way of thinking: isnull is cheking whether LoginName is null and if it is, then it assigns ' ' (which is also null, right?) and then compares it to ' '(null?). And then, if the expression is true - assigns a null to a variable LoginName (why? it was already null in the first place!). 
Can someone plz shed some light into my dark head. I simply don't understand the logic. Thank you.

Comment: NULL and '' are different things.

Comment: @Rob: unless you were using Oracle. Maybe user2785029 was using Oracle before and there an empty string is treated as NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether @LoginName is NULL or '', it forces @LoginName to NULL.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Well that is sort of silly. Should be:

```
IF @LoginName = ''
BEGIN 
    SET@LoginName = null
END
```

The code was an attempt to make sure both NULLs and empty string values were handled, but no need to convert nulls to empty string to convert back to null, you only need to convert the empty string if it comes in as that.

Comment: I always put a BEGIN and END on IF statements, makes for less surprises during maintenance.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! I used to work in Oracle where as a_horse_with_no_name pointed out these two are the same thing.